# Is manual copying between component data and form data required on save/load from web API?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my reactive form, whenever I save the data, I get back the stored object back from the server. (The reason is that there **might** be server logic altering a field, which then needs to be distributed back to the client.)

```
onSave() {
  const data = this.form.value;
  console.log("saving", data);

  this.service.save(data)
    .subscribe(
      suc => {
        this.data = suc;
        console.log("saving succeeded", suc);
      },
      err => console.log("saving failed", err)
    );
}
```

I noticed that the changes in the data model don't affect the controls on my page. Realizing that, I'm resetting the value of the form by an explicit *this.form.setValue(this.data)* as shown below.

```
onSave() {
  const data = this.form.value; ...
  this.service.save(data)
    .subscribe(
      suc => {
        this.data = suc;
        this.form.setValue(this.data);
      }, ...
    );
}
```

It produces the desired effect but it seems a bit hacky and I can't shake off the sensation that I'm hiding a design flaw rather than resolving it. I suspect that the connection between the component data and form data need to be coupled automagically. At the moment, I copy data manually from form to component before saving and copy back after saving. (Since it needs to be done each time, for every operation, I sense that there should be a feature facilitating it in a like-a-boss'y way.)

Am I doing it right or is there a step I missed?

Comment: You are doing it correctly but I think if you get successful response that means the data injected correctly as what you sent before and there is no need to update form in client with same data.

Comment: From my point of view, your  code looks fine. Except few lines: `const data = this.form.value;`  and `this.data = suc;`. I think  them are  useless. You can directly  pass  form value and data without creation of new  references.

Comment: Agree with fateme if Konrad want the same data on form there is no need to reset the form

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr I see why you get the impression of useless code. I have omitted (as of no relevance to the question) the fact that the form has a reset function that's supposed to get back to the version of data as it was while loaded originally before a user tampered it. A bit like reloading but without a trip to the server. Would you still claim they are useless or does my approach make sense?

Comment: @FatemeFazli Let me emphasize the reason to reset the form. It's possible that the server returns the same object as we sent to it **but with a slight change**, e.g. a date of update or maybe a correction of city name etc. So the object returned on the successful response might be different from what we have on the client (and being more correct and up to date). Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?. The patchValue function?

```
onSave() {
  const data = this.form.value; ...
  this.service.save(data)
    .subscribe(
      suc => {
        this.form.patchValue(suc);
      }, ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you know What's the difference between setValue and patchValue?

Comment: setValue resets the form keys with the incoming JSON object, While patchValue updates the form control value with incoming object.

Comment: The difference between *setValue* and *patchValue* is, according to my understanding of docs, that the former requires an exact match of fields provided (full object) while the latter is more elastic and accepts both subsets and supersets, trying to do the best matching the fields to already existing model. Anyway, yes, I've tried patching and it didn't procude any difference, as far I could see.

Comment: Can you please make a stackblitz example? It will help us to figure this out?